# Problem with the if statement in temperature calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

The error I get shows up whether I initialize variables or not and I don't understand the nature of it.  I've checked the structure of the "if statement" and it looks legit. I've checked the spelling and just in case copy-pasted all variables, still it persists.  A hint is greatly appreciated.
I am supposed to take a value of the degrees, then ask what scale it is and convert it to the opposite accordingly.

(The file has been edited but there are some logical errors that remain.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#welcome screen
print("******************************************")
print("**  Temperature Conversion Calculator   **")
print("******************************************")
print("**       Enter 999 to end input         **")
print("******************************************")


#initialize variables
#temp = 0
#temp_scale = ""
#temp_conv = 0

#input and calculations
while True:
    temp = float(input("Enter temperature:  "))
    if temp == 999:
        break
    else:
        scale = input("Is this Celsius or Fahrenheit (C/F)?")
        if scale.lower() == "c":
            temp_conv = float(round((temp - 32) * 5 / 9))
            temp_scale = "Celsius"          
        elif scale.lower() == "f":
            temp_conv = float(round((9 * temp) / 5 + 32))
            temp_scale = "Fahrenheit"
        else:
            print("Wrong input.  Please try again.")        
        
        #format and display the result
        print("******************************************")
        print("The temperature in ", temp_scale, " is ", temp_conv, " degrees.")
        print("******************************************") 

#end program
print("Bye!")
```

[image: python3 syntax error]

Comment: A bracket is missing at the end of this line: scale = string(input("Is this Celsius or Fahrenheit (C/F)?")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing a parethensis. `scale = string(input("Is this Celsius or Fahrenheit (C/F)?")` should be `scale = string(input("Is this Celsius or Fahrenheit (C/F)?"))`. Another problem in your code is that you use `string()` to convert to string while it should be `str()`. You also do not have a break statement near `elif scale.lower() == "f"`. You don't need the second argument `2` in the `float` function.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is actually on the line before.  You've got two open parentheses and only one close parenthesis.

On that note, what is the `string` function you're calling?  If you're trying to turn the result of `input` into a `str`, then you would do

```
str(input(...))
```

However, `input` returns a string already and so the conversion is redundant.